# Changing static map coordinates from .xaml file with variables in C# code on Xamarin.Forms.Maps Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I use Map on Xamarin.Forms.Maps.

On my iOS project, code in my MianPage.xaml look like this:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <maps:Map MapType="Hybrid"
              x:Name="map"
              HeightRequest="250">
         <x:Arguments>
            <maps:MapSpan>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <maps:Position>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:Double>42.510578</x:Double>
                            <x:Double>27.461014</x:Double>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </maps:Position>
                    <x:Double>0.02</x:Double>
                    <x:Double>0.02</x:Double>
                </x:Arguments>
            </maps:MapSpan>
         </x:Arguments>
    </maps:Map>
</StackLayout>
```

In C# code, I created one task which gets your GPS locations (Lat, Lon) and want to change the position on my map using position from GPS.

The code from MainPage.xaml.cs look like this:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    ChangeMapLocation();
}

public void ChangeMapLocation()
{
    Position position = new Position(Convert.ToDouble(GlobalLat), Convert.ToDouble(GlobalLong));
    MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01);
    map = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map(mapSpan);
    mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromKilometers(0.444));
    map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
}
```

I tried like that but the coords is the same with this in my first MainPage.xaml

```xml
<x:Double>42.510578</x:Double>
<x:Double>27.461014</x:Double>
```

What can I do to display the new coords from the C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a new instance of Map

```
Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map map = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map();
```

when you should be using the instance that is already declared in your XAML

```
<maps:Map MapType="Hybrid" x:Name="map" HeightRequest="250" >
```

just remove the first line where you instantiate a new map

Comment: When I remove Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map map = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map(); location is still not changed.. I try to created a new method and put only code for the map and after I calling this method in the constructor and map still not change the location..

Comment: in your revised code your are still creating a new instance of the map